# How to change the popup hover state to active state (on click) in vue.js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am using a popup menu in my code, so whenever I hover the icon it shows the popup.

Everything is working fine but I need to change the state of popup from hover to active.

**Intend behavior**:
Whenever I click the icon, the popup should show and when I click the icon again it should close them(like toggle ).

I tried changing hover state to active , but that works partially. The popup loads milliseconds on click , but I am not getting as toggle behavior.

I am adding the code below , kindly check to them.

```
<template>
    <div class="popup">
        <font-awesome-icon :icon="infoIcon" />
        <span class="tooltip" id="myPopup"> <b>Popupheader</b><br />Popup
            content</span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
    import { faInfoCircle } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid';


    computed: {
        infoIcon() {
            return faInfoCircle;
        },
    },
</script>


<style>
```

```
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.popup .tooltip {
  background: $custom-control-indicator-bg;
  bottom: 100%;
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: $dark-color;
  display: block;
  left: -140px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;

  width: 300px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
       -o-transform: translateY(10px);
          transform: translateY(10px);
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
       -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
          transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
      -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
       -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
}

/* This bridges the gap so you can mouse into the tooltip without it disappearing */
.popup .tooltip:before {
  bottom: -20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}  

/* CSS Triangles - see Trevor's post */
.popup .tooltip:after {
  border-left: solid transparent 10px;
  border-right: solid transparent 10px;
  border-top: solid $custom-control-indicator-bg 10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  left: 51%;
  margin-left: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}

.popup:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
       -o-transform: translateY(0px);
          transform: translateY(0px);

}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the :active property on a non clickable element will only trigger a onclick on and off effect. What you actually see. If you want to have a toggle effect you have two options:

1. You actually use a clickable element to wrap your span such as a button
2. You use javascript to change your class

```
   function myFunction() {
    var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
  }
```

You must adapt this to your situation by attaching this kind of function to your click event.